# Exchanging the order of integration in improper double integrals

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

My question arise from  *Improper Riemann Integrals* by Ioannis M. Roussos
[image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

---

Why the improper double integral is absolutely convergent,then we can exchange order of integration in improper Riemann sense? I really don't understand that it said  $\textbf{Condition II}\ \Longleftrightarrow \textbf{Condition III} \Longleftrightarrow \textbf{Condition IV}$ and each one of them can ensure the equalities

$$ \iint_{\mathbf{R}^2} f(x,y) \, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}y
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left[ \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y) \, \mathrm{d}x \right] \, \mathrm{d}y
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left[ \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y) \, \mathrm{d}y \right] \, \mathrm{d}x $$
hold. This has been bothering me for a long time！Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

---

I got a counterexample function $f(x,y)$ as following which is discontinuous on $[0,1]\times[0,1].$

$f(x,y)$ is defined on $\left [0,1  \right ] \times\left [ 0,1 \right ] $
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
  2^n,\quad x=\frac{2m-1}{2^n}\text{ and }0<y\le\frac{1}{2^n}\\
\quad \left ( n=1,2,\ldots;m=1,2,\ldots,2^{n-1} \right ) ,\\
  0,  \text{ otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$
$\textbf(1).$ For any $\varepsilon>0,$ $$\iint_{[0,1]\times[\varepsilon ,1]} f(x,y)\,dx\,dy=0 \Rightarrow $$$$\iint_{[0,1]\times[0 ,1]} f(x,y) \, dx\, dy = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \iint_{[0,1]\times[\varepsilon ,1]} f(x,y) \, dx \, dy = 0.$$

$\textbf(2).$ For any fixed $y\in\left [ 0,1 \right ],$ $$ \int_0^1 f(x,y) \, dx=0\Rightarrow \int_0^1 dy \int_0^1 f(x,y) \, dx = 0.$$

$\textbf(3).$

When $x\in[0,1]$ but $x\ne\frac{2m-1}{2^n}\left ( n=1,2,\ldots;m=1,2,\ldots,2^{n-1} \right ) ,$ we get $\int_0^1 f(x,y) \, dy = 0;$

When $x\in[0,1]$ and $x=\frac{2m-1}{2^n}\left ( n=1,2,\ldots;m=1,2,\ldots,2^{n-1} \right ) ,$ we get $$\int_0^1 f(x,y) \, dy = \int_0^{\frac{1}{2^n}}f(x,y) \, dy=1.$$

So $$ \int_0^1 dx\int_0^1 f(x,y) \, dy$$ does not exist in Riemann sense!

---

I am definitely not disagreeing with Fubini's Theorem. Actually,I want find a counterexample/example  $f(x,y)$ is bounded or unbounded,continuous  on some region $\mathcal{R}$ which is bounde or unbounded and not necessarily closed or open and the function $f(x,y)$  satisfies the $\textbf{Condition IV}$,

but

$$ \text{ the improper double integral } \iint_{\mathbf{R}^2}  \lvert f(x,y) \rvert \, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}y < \infty \nRightarrow \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left[ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \lvert f(x,y) \rvert \, \mathrm{d}x \right] \mathrm{d}y < \infty ;$$
and $$\text{ the improper double integral } \iint_{\mathbf{R}^2}  \lvert f(x,y) \rvert \, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}y < \infty \nRightarrow \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left[ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \lvert f(x,y) \rvert \, \mathrm{d}y \right] \, \mathrm{d}x < \infty.$$

further,the the equalities

$$ \iint_{\mathbf{R}^2} f(x,y) \, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}y
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left[ \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y) \, \mathrm{d}x \right] \, \mathrm{d}y
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left[ \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y) \, \mathrm{d}y \right] \, \mathrm{d}x $$ can not hold.

Comment: With the counterexample, you have $g(x) = \int_0^1 f(x,y) \, dy = 1$ for all $x = \frac{2m-1}{2^n}$ and $g(x) = 0$ otherwise.   It is not not just discontinuous on a nonzero measure set, it is discontinuous at every point in $[0,1]$. Thus $g$ is not Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$. Is it clear to you why this does not contradict the theorem on exchanging integrals?

Comment: Then you ask if there is a counterexample where $f$ is continuous.  No -- there is not if the region of integration is a closed rectangle.  If $f:[a,b]\times [c,d] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then $$\int_a^b \left( \int_c^d f(x,y) \, dy \right) \, dx = \int_c^d \left( \int_a^b f(x,y) \, dx \right) \, dy$$

Comment: @RRL If $f(x,y)$ is continuous on a closed bounded rectangle $[a,b]\times[c,d],$  we can assure $$ \iint_{[a,b]\times[c,d]} f(x,y) \, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}y
= \int_{c}^{d} \left[ \int_{a}^{b} f(x,y) \, \mathrm{d}x \right] \, \mathrm{d}y
= \int_{a}^{b} \left[ \int_{c}^{d} f(x,y) \, \mathrm{d}y \right] \, \mathrm{d}x $$ (it's a trivial conclusion of Fubini's theorem in Riemann sense).

Comment: Are you asking for an example where $f$ is continuous and $\int_a^\infty \left(\int_c^d f(x,y) \, dy \right) \, dx \neq \int_c^d\left(\int_a^\infty f(x,y) \, dx \right) \, dy$  or where   $\int_a^\infty \left(\int_c^\infty f(x,y) \, dy \right) \, dx \neq \int_c^\infty\left(\int_a^\infty f(x,y) \, dx \right) \, dy$ ?  In other words, the improper integrals all converge but the iterated integrals are not equal.

Comment: @RRL I just revise my post in order to better interpret my intentions. Thank you for your effort !

Answer (score 2):

Further clarification here is warranted.

Note that

$$f(x,y) = (2xy-2x^3y^3)e^{-x^2y^2} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}x^2ye^{-x^2y^2} = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}xy^2e^{-x^2y^2}$$

Hence,

$$\int_0^\infty f(x,y)\, dx = \left.x^2ye^{-x^2y^2} \right|_{x=0}^{x\to\infty} = 0, \quad \int_0^1 f(x,y)\, dy = \left.xy^2e^{-x^2y^2} \right|_{y=0}^{y=1} = xe^{-x^2},$$

and

$$\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^\infty f(x,y)\, dx \right)  dy=0, \quad \int_0^\infty \left(\int_0^1 f(x,y)\, dy \right)  dx=\int_0^\infty xe^{-x^2} \, dx= \frac{1}{2}$$

Thus, $f$ is continuous on $[0,\infty] \times [0,1]$, all improper integrals converge, but the order of integration cannot be switched. However, the condition $\int_0^\infty \int_0^1 |f(x,y)| \, d(x,y) < \infty$ does not hold so this is not a counterexample to the revised question.

Also, you have given an example (and it is not difficult to find others)  where the improper double Riemann integral of $|f|$ converges but the iterated integrals are not equal (because one does not exist as an improper Riemann integral).  However, the function $f$ is discontinuous in these cases.

There remains the question of finding a counterexample where $f$ is absolutely integrable, $f$ is continuous, and the iterated integrals are unequal and/or do not exist as improper Riemann integrals.  If it is true in the sense of the improper Riemann integral, that

$$\int \int_{\mathbb{R}^2}|f(x,y)| \, d(x,y)< \infty,$$

and in addition $f$ is continuous, then  both Riemann and Lebesgue integrals exist and coincide over finite regions. It also follows that the double integral over $\mathbb{R}^2$ exists in the sense of Lebesgue  and Fubini’s theorem implies equality of the iterated integrals of $f$ also in the sense of Lebesgue. The question then reduces to whether or not

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left( \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y) \, dy \right)dx, \quad\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left( \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y) \, dx \right)dy$$

can fail to exist as iterated improper Riemann integrals (or exist and be unequal).  I suspect -- at this moment -- when $f$ is both continuous and absolutely integrable, that it can be shown using the DCT that this cannot be true.

Comment: Is it $$\iint_{[0,\infty]\times[0,1]}  \lvert f(x,y) \rvert \, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}y < \infty \quad ?$$

Comment: @Elisa: No — that integral of $|f|$ does not converge in this example.   If it did then the iterated integrals would be equal.  I’m not sure any longer what the question really is.  If the integral with respect to the product measure converges absolutely then we can interchange the iterated integrals and all are equal.

Comment: **What the question really is** :I want find a counterexample  $f(x,y)$ is bounded or unbounded,continuous  on some region $\mathcal{R}$ which is bounde or unbounded and not necessarily closed or open and the function $f(x,y)$  satisfies the $\textbf{Condition IV}$ (the improper double integral $\iint_{\mathbf{R}^2}  \lvert f(x,y) \rvert \, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}y < \infty $),but the $\textbf{Condition II}$/ $\textbf{Condition III}$ can not hold.

Comment: In your example,
$$\iint_{[0,\infty]\times[0,1]}  \lvert f(x,y) \rvert \, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}y =\int_{0}^{\infty} \left[ \int_{0}^{1}|f(x,y)| \, \mathrm{d}y \right] \, \mathrm{d}x=\int_{0}^{1} \left[ \int_{0}^{\infty}|f(x,y)| \, \mathrm{d}x \right] \, \mathrm{d}y=\infty.$$

Comment: Maybe you understand my question in Lebesgue's sense,but I discussed it in improper Riemann sense.I think that 's the reason why you said you can't sure  what the question really is.

Comment: @Elisa: I am looking at it in the sense of both integrals.  If $f$ has an absolutely convergent improper Riemann integral then it is also Lebesgue integrable and by Fubini's theorem the double integral must equal the iterated integrals -- although the iterated integrals may only exist in the Lebesgue sense.  So you want a counterexample where the improper Riemann integral converges absolutely, but there is not equality with the iterated integrals (when considered as improper Riemann integrals).  Then you also want $f$ to be continuous.

Comment: That counterexample probably requires the iterated integrals do not exist (in the Riemann sense) like the example you gave -- however with continuity of $f$ imposed I don't see how to get it.  Recall that for a finite rectangle $A \times B \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ where $f$ is Riemann integrable on $A \times B$, it is always true that $$\int_{A\times B} f = \int_A \left(\overline{\int_B} f(x,y) \, dy \right) dx = \int_A \left(\underline{\int_B} f(x,y) \, dy \right) dx$$  So if $f$ is continuous the upper and lower integrals must be equal.

Comment: From your last two comments, I am sure you have already get what's the really question I've been trying to solve although you have yet to take a specific counterexample.Thanks for your clue about how to get !